# How to make Sliding and jigsaw puzzle In Android?

Tags: java, android, xml

Can anybody tell me how to do sliding puzzle and jigsaw in android ? Or is there any third party library to do that ? looking forward to know about it.

I would be grateful if anybody provide a link of source.

thanks in advance

Comment: Pls read [How To Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a query in stackoverflow

Comment: @prasad I am new here , will read that and will try to improve myself...thankew

Answer (score 0):

I'd advise you use [Unity 2D Mode](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/2d-game-creation/2d-mode) for games like that. It is easy to use and can be easily built for both android and iOS.

Not to mention you are sure to find people doing the exact same thing as you.

Comment: Sorry bro..its a part of my project..

Need to work in studio only

Comment: @Zuhad Then I advise you look up tutorials online... There should be plenty. And if you're new to Android Studio try Udacity or [Google's](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/index.html) tutorials

Comment: Goncalves Thank you very much. Will look into it :)